# jQuery syntax juaxtoposing two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a line of jQuery code which I don't understand.

```
    var layerid = $('ul.layerstack li.selected').data('layerid');
```

I understand that `$(ul.layerstack)` is to select `ul` elements with `layerstack` class, and similarly for `li.selected`. But I don't understand the syntax for juxtaposing the two with a space in between.

Can someone please help explain this syntax and give a reference for this? (The DOM structure is listed below for reference).

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called as the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector)... it is a part of css selector spec.

It is used to select all elements which satisfies the second selector which are inside the first part

- [Descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

> A space means "any descendant of": direct children and children of those children would be selected.